# How to edit Root.plist in settings.bundle?

Tags: iphone, settings.bundle

I created a `Settings.bundle` file for my iOS project. The generated file has already some data so when I build and run the app the settings show up in the iPhone settings for my app.

But when I edit the Root.plist file it can not be safed anymore, it stays some kind of grey.

[image]

Why can it not be safed? How do I solve that problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved that problem. It seems that it is not possible to save the Root.plist from the window you see in my question.

You have to double click on Root.plist and save it in the seperate window that pops up.